# letsencrypt ssl install shortcut

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, lets-encrypt

I am currently using letsencrypt for SSL certificates on my server. As the amount of sites on my server is forever increasing, its becoming very time consuming installing a certificate running the ssh command: `letsencrypt`. I have to manually uncheck all domains that i dont want an SSL installed on.

My question: is there some sort of shortcut for example running the following: `letsencrypt mydomain.com` to install a certificate for the specified domain? I cant seem to find anything in the documentation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The help says :

```
letsencrypt  --help
letsencrypt  [SUBCOMMAND] [options] [-d domain] [-d domain] ...
```

So you should be able to do what you want with `letsencrypt -d mydomain.com`

Answer (score 0):

If you have certboot it is easy to run the following:

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

or apache

```
 sudo certbot --apache -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

Have a look at [digitalocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04)